# R 3.1.0 crashes with segfault when loading data.table package 1.9.2

Tags: r, data.table

I got a problem with the data.table package 1.9.2 when loading the package under R 3.1.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.2). R crashes as soon as I want to load the precompiled package. Compilation also crashes.

This is my output for doing library(data.table):

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 7: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 8: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 9: asNamespace(ns)
10: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
11: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
12: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
13: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
14: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
15: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
16: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
17: library(data.table)
```

Here is my output for self-compiling with install.packages("data.table", type = "source"):

```
> install.packages("data.table", type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/Users/sascha/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
versuche URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.9.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1021871 bytes (997 Kb)
URL geöffnet
==================================================
downloaded 997 Kb

Loading packages…

Welcome to R at 12:45:18 

* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** Paket ‘data.table’ erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastradixdouble.c -o fastradixdouble.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastradixint.c -o fastradixint.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c forder.c -o forder.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fread.c -o fread.o
fread.c:602:95: warning: while loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        if (ch<eof && *ch=='\"') {while(++ch<eof && *ch!=eol && !(*ch=='\"' && *(ch-1)!='\\')); if (ch<eof && *ch++!='\"') {sprintf(errormsg, "Format error on line %d: '%.*s'", nline, (int)(ch-pos+1), pos);EXIT();} }
                                                                                              ^
fread.c:602:95: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
1 warning generated.
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c gsumm.c -o gsumm.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c rbindlist.c -o rbindlist.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c reorder.c -o reorder.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c uniqlist.c -o uniqlist.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c vecseq.c -o vecseq.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c wrappers.c -o wrappers.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -o data.table.so assign.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fastradixdouble.o fastradixint.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o fread.o gsumm.o init.o rbindlist.o reorder.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
mv data.table.so datatable.so
installing to /Users/sascha/Library/R/3.1/library/data.table/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 7: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 8: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 9: asNamespace(ns)
10: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
11: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc, keep.source, partial = TRUE)
12: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
13: suppressPackageStartupMessages(loadNamespace(package, lib.loc,     keep.source, partial = TRUE))
14: code2LazyLoadDB(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, keep.source = keep.source,     compress = compress)
15: makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)
16: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
17: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
18: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
19: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
20: try({    suppressPackageStartupMessages(.getRequiredPackages(quietly = TRUE))    makeLazyLoading(pkg_name, lib, keep.source = keep.source)})
21: do_install_source(pkg_name, instdir, pkg, desc)
22: do_install(pkg)
23: tools:::.install_packages()
aborting ...
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34:   577 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
       578 Segmentation fault: 11  | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --slave --args ${args}
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/df/4k_zm03d1jl4dfmy51py_qxc0000gn/T/Rtmp3Kk7aK/downloaded_packages’
```

Any ideas?!?

Comment: It seems to work using the R Snow Leopard builds from CRAN, not the builds for Mavericks... strange.

Comment: Please submit the full report (as above) to r-sig-mac mailing list, as Simon's more likely to respond there.

Comment: Before going on with Carl's suggestion, could you try it on the development version from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)?? (Check the README.md file for installation instructions).

Answer (score 1):

I just learned through a painful similar experience that data.table depends on OpenMP, but the default number of threads set by data.table seems like its the max number available.  My issue was resolved when I set the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to 1 before running.  EG in a csh script before running R and my R job,

setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 1

Comment: This question is 4 years old with old versions of R and data.table.  We're currently on R 3.5.1 and data.table 1.11.8.   We check v1.11.8 with R 3.1.0 so you should be fine on R 3.1.0 with data.table v1.11.8.  Which versions do you have?

Comment: I encountered the issue using R 3.4.1 and data.table 1.11.8.

Comment: That's odd then.  Are you on Mac, Linux or Windows?   And are you using CRAN binaries or compiling yourself?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem both on Windows (where I have 8 cores) and on a Linux cluster (where I have 32 cores/node and run with a bunch of random seeds split over a hundred nodes).  It only seems to occur after running gazillions of calls to data.table functions-- but it's reproducible for certain random seeds. But setting the env variable as I described above totally solves the problem.  I'm installing data.tables via install.packages() calls to CRAN.  As far as the R installation I did it on Windows myself but the systems guru at my workplace installed it on our Linux cluster....

Comment: (by the way @MattDowle -- data.table has revolutionized my work life.... thanks a million.)

Comment: Thanks. Could you create a reproducible example and file it on GitHub? Either with dummy data or obfuscated private data.